# 404 not found error on WordPress local host on wpn-xm

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wpn-xm

I am trying to develop a WordPress site on my local host. 
 i am using `wpn-xm` as a local server. but after change my permalink from `plain` to `post name`, all the pages redirect to 404 error page.

can anyone please tell me, how can i solve this problem?

Thank You

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like with WPN-XM, you have to manually add the rewrite rules yourself (since it doesn't have mod_rewrite available). Instructions on this can be found here:

http://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: Thank you,
but i have seen that Nginx is already running in WPN-XM. but as i am a new WPN-XM user, i don't know how to do that?

Comment: I have follow the instruction from this site [link](http://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/) and added the following lines of code on config file. <br> `location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}` and restart the server. but until now it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup Nginx specific rewrite rules, because WordPress cannot do that automatically for you. Instructions you can find on [wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx) or [nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/).

Comment: Thank you,
but i have seen that Nginx is already running in WPN-XM. but as i am a new WPN-XM user, i don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The WPN-XM project has a folder with a lot of Nginx configs available, see

https://github.com/WPN-XM/software/tree/master/nginx/config/conf/sites-disabled

You are looking for Wordpress:

https://github.com/WPN-XM/software/blob/master/nginx/config/conf/sites-disabled/wordpress.conf

1. adjust the wordpress location

   Here it's `www/wordpress`, but yours might be `www\my_wordpress-1.2.3` or something else
2. make sure the file gets included in the `nginx.conf`